# Extrmely high gas consumption in solidity contract even if it is called a real simple method

Tags: solidity

i have deployed that simple contract

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract testGasLimits{

    uint b;
    constructor(){
        b = 0;
    }

    function testGasA(uint a) public{
        b = a;
    }

    function testGasB() public{

    }

    receive() external payable {}
    fallback() external payable {}
}
```

I expected that txs calling the above methods would use/need (in term of gas)

testGasA : around 21.000 + 20.000 gas (base + store), **41000 gas**

testGasB: around **21.000 gas** + something maybe tiny? (it doesn't matter)

My main problem is that for the above methods the first tx (testGasA) spent **237956 gas**
and the latter **230392 gas**

Any clue what is happening and my contract calls uses so meny gas for no clear reason?

*Chain tested Goerli, Arbitrum, Mainnet,
Remix 0.8.17 compiler*

Comment: I'm getting transaction costs 43,724 for `testGasA()` and 21,186 for `testGasB()` in Remix VM (Merge). Can you please edit the question and provide steps to reproduce the large values, or link some public transactions (on the testnets) with these numbers?

Comment: @PetrHejda At VM runs have similar results but take a look at arbitrum, how is that possible https://arbiscan.io/tx/0x9f50c66416e2175d39b90490e56a89cc7e91f6c56e1a780a6c05776818814050

Comment: this is very good question. +1. I debugged the transaction and function call cost 22124 and 22100 is for `sstore` opcode to store the data. the total execution gas is 44.000 and I could not figure out where is other 22000 gas spent for.